# Phonertc demo crash in android6

Tags: android, cordova, demo, phonertc

I'm using cordova 6.0.0, cordova@android 5.1.0, Android 6 and phoneRTC plugin 
https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc.git

My app is working and the demo in the plugin code too with cordova 6.0.0, cordova@android 5.1.0 and android 5.x.x.
https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc/tree/master/demo/client

But I build the app and demo for android 6 (on nexus5) and it crashes when you start the videochat.

Anyone have this problem?

Comment: Did you solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to config.xml:

```
<platform name="android">
        <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="22" />
</platform>
```